# get_template_directory() still returning path to previous theme

Tags: templates, directory

In WordPress, I've been installing and using various themes, including 2013, Roots, and now BlankSlate. I noticed that now that I've activated BlankSlate, the function `get_template_directory()` used in front-page.php is still returning the path to the Roots theme directory. My current front-page.php looks like this.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section id="content" role="main">
       <img class="frontpageimg" src="<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/images/slogan-2.png">


       <h4>In the Los Angeles area? </h4> <p>Ask about free demo loaners! </p>
       <h4>We also take mail orders.</h4> On all orders, there is a 30-day return policy!</p> 



       <img src = "<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/assets/img/cables-ers-absorber-700.jpg"/></a>
       <img src = "<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/assets/img/blueprint-silencers-v2-700.jpg"/></a>
       <img src = "<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/assets/img/brav-front-page-700.jpg"/></a>

        <a href="contact" class="btn btn-lg btn-orange">Contact Us</a>

</section>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

EDIT UPDATE:
Did some some debugging as follows:

Deactivated all plugins. Logged out, cleared cache. The problem persisted.

Switched from BlankSlate (in which the problem was evident) to 2013 theme. Similar behavior, although I now can say more specifically what that behavior is. While in the 2013 theme, apparently the PHP construct `<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>/path-in-2013-theme/file.jpg` works, but `<?php get_template_directory(); ?>` returns the path to the Roots theme. The same is true of `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>` (works correctly with the `echo` but not without).

However, the behavior is somewhat different in BlankSlate. Without the `echo` both `get_template_directory()` and `get_template_directory_uri()` return the path to Roots theme, while with the `echo` they do something else (but I'm not sure what that something else is.. how do I dump these values for debugging?)

FURTHER DEBUGGING:

I was able to inspect the page source with Firebug. Sure enough, the functions had no output without echo. So the image source was `src="/assets/img/brav-banner-3.jpg` and so forth. And that worked in some themes. I mean I could see the image. So maybe it's a caching problem? When I added the echo and changed the path to the jpg, I was able to get it to work in the BlankSlate theme. So I am going to mark this solved, as a caching issue.

Comment: Try logging out, cleaning cache of your browser and then logging in. If that still doesn't work, I think you should post more details about your setup; it sounds as if an error occurred while you were switching the themes.

Comment: I checked out the theme `BlankSlate` and in the default package where was no such a file as `front-page.php`. Have you made it yourself? From your post is not entirely clear what a theme you have activated, whether you have customized it. And the last thing, when you use `get_template_directory`, it returns an absolute path, which you would use, when including/requiring files, for loading stuff from your theme folder to public, like CSS, IMGs, JSs, use `get_template_directory_uri`

Comment: Please do basic troubleshooting. Do you have any **Plugins active**? Does the problem persist with **all Plugins disabled**? Does this happen only with the Blank Slate Theme, or does it happen **with a core-bundled Theme (such as Twenty Twelve or Twenty Thirteen)**? If the problem persists with a core-bundled Theme active, then the problem is probably with something the **Roots Theme** did. In that case, try a **clean install** of WordPress, with no Plugins active.

Comment: P.S. Roots Theme [screws with relative URLs and rewrites](http://roots.io/roots-101/#theme-functionality). Try flushing your rewrite rules, and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I will proceed with debugging. Ivan, your last sentence is hard to decipher... can you try rewriting it? I think you are saying I should switch to get_template_directory_uri. I did add front-page.php myself.

Comment: Updated the question with debugging information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The get_template_directory() and get_template_directory_uri() functions don't actually echo anything at all. They will make no output at all unless you echo them.

So your code that looks like this:

```
<img class="frontpageimg" src="<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/images/slogan-2.png">
```

Should actually cause this output:

```
<img class="frontpageimg" src="/images/slogan-2.png">
```

Which may not be what you're expecting. Examine the source of the page. And add that echo, it's not optional. :)

Also, if the theme may have screwed with relative urls and rewrites and such, as Chip suggests, then your browser is caching. Browser caching is notoriously difficult to debug. I like to use Chrome and the inspector tool, because when you have it open, right-clicking on the reload button gives you a "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" which does more what you expect it to do as far as showing the real truth of the matter.

Comment: I assure you it works without the echo in the Roots theme. Did Roots screw with these functions?

Comment: When everything is preceded by or includes "*in the Roots Theme*", that is a pretty clear indication that the *root* cause of the issue is... the *Roots Theme*.

Comment: Well, it also works without the echo in 2013, just returning the path to the Roots assets directory. But before I install Chrome and try "hard reload" can someone tell me how to inspect the output of these functions directly, or look at the source code? Seems like a more direct approach. Oh, I did clear the cache in Firefox. EDIT: I just realized I can inspect the pages with Firebug. Doing that now. Will report back.

Comment: See original question for further debugging info. Marked as solved (for now).